# can clients see server side source code ? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side

I would like to know if somehow any client using any browser can see my server side code? if it is so how could I prevent this and actually what is the client able to see when he is visiting my web site?

(asp.net)

Comment: No they cant see your server code. They can only interact with your GUI. they cant see server side code.

Comment: No Server Side code is rendered on server and client receives only HTML of equivalent of it. When user access your website he/she received only the HTML output after processing the business logic of server code along with the javascript, css and images which resides on client machine for supporting the HTML.

Comment: Well, if you don't set up an error page then the client will see some server side code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used asp.net before, but i assume it's the same like PHP or Perl. The client only sees what the server is sending to him (like any other network application).

The normal order of execution of things should be ->
A client sends a request to a specific resource. Your server interprets this request and opens the required files for processing. Then a parser goes through your source files and executes your code.

The only way of source code being send to the client is a typo where you miss the " at the end of your strings.

Comment: "The only way of source code being send to the client is a typo where you miss the " at the end of your strings" .. What?

Comment: PHP-Examble: echo "asadasd; (further code ...) - and then somehow manage to get the code still correct so it will get displayed to the user.